# Delete and refresh a record in DBgrid where u maintain the same position

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe2, record, dbgrid

I have a small database I'm using dbgo, I have a DBgrid displaying my records, I need to know how to delete a record and refresh the database where the index arrow stays in the same position or at least go to the next? but currently my index arrow jump to start form the beginning each time I refresh !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep  and reset Recno

```
var
I:Integer;
.......

I := Ads.Recno;
Ads.Delete;
Ads.Recno := I;
```

an example implementation for usage with DBNavigator could be

```
Procedure DeleteAndKeepRecno(Ads: TCustomAdoDataset);
var
  rn: Integer;
begin
  rn := Ads.RecNo;
  Ads.Delete;
  Ads.RecNo := rn;
end;

procedure TForm4.DBNavigator1Click(Sender: TObject; Button: TNavigateBtn);
begin
  if Button = nbDelete then
  begin
    DeleteAndKeepRecno (TCustomAdoDataset(TDBNavigator(Sender).DataSource.DataSet));
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There was [`an article`](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/dbgrid_row_pos.htm) showing the similar for a dataset refresh. [+1]

Comment: I knew it was simple, I just thought the Delphi will not accept it but it did !!! many thaks