# Deleting a entry in a DBGrid with a button in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm relatively new to delphi and I would like to know how to delete an entry in a dbGrid without using a dbNavigator but a button. The number of the entry that should be deleted must be entered in a spinedit, not be clicked on in the dbGrid. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should perform the action on the dataset and not on the grid - thats why the navigator is also linked to the dataset/datasource and not to the grid. You can locate the row and then delete the matched row `TDataSet.Locate` `TDataSet.Delete`

Comment: depending on your dataset type (ADO/ClientDataset/?) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600289/delete-and-refresh-a-record-in-dbgrid-where-u-maintain-the-same-position) post might help.

Comment: Why, oh why, do you want to make life harder for yourself and your users? Unless you have a *really* good reason not to use a button (be it a navigator or otherwise), I would stick to what users can understand intuitively (a delete button deletes the record).

Answer (score 2):

First it's nice to position in the first record of the DataSet, then it will delete from the first to the N record.

```
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.First;
```

Now you create the Loop (Don't forget to create the variable {**var I : integer**})

```
For I:=0 to SpinEdit1.Value-1 Do
```

Before start deleting records, you will need to verify if there is any record on DataSet. 
You can do something like this:

```
if DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount > 0 then
```

And finally you can delete the record

```
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Delete;
```

The final code would be like this:

```
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.First; //Set on the first Record of the DataSet
For I:=0 to SpinEdit1.Value-1 Do //Do loop
   if DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount > 0 then //Check if have records
       DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Delete; //Delete
```